Tax Treatment of Emancipated Minors
If a child (16 years old) was emancipated by a court ruling and if we assume that the tests for "Qualifying Child", "Dependent", and "Child Tax Credit" are still met, would the parents (with whom he still lives) be able to claim him/her as a dependent?  Would eligibility for the Child Tax Credit be affected?  Are there other tax implications for the parents?  Are there implications for matters of inheritance and probate?  Note that the child provides no more than half of their own financial support, lives with the parents for more than half a year, remains an unmarried U.S. citizen, and wishes to be properly claimed as a dependent.  Also, there is no dispute between the parents and the child.  I am raising the question here because I cannot find any mention of emancipated minors in the IRS publications.  Any cited sources will be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Emancipation ends the legal authority that a parent has over a child who is under 18 (source). As long as the tax definition doesn't involve parents having legal authority over the minor - the emancipation is irrelevant. For the purposes you've mentioned, the definitions do not involve it.

Thank you for the answer.  That was the impression I got from reading the IRS publications.  It just seemed like this issue isn't discussed very much and I wanted to seek a bit of confirmation.  Thanks again.
